# How do I bake my texture for animation?

Tags: rendering, texture-baking

I am working on my first ever animation, and I have realised if I turn off the material for my "ship" it drops the render time per frame by 50% for me, which is huge as they are around 1hr10min per frame at the moment.

I have tried to follow some tutorials, but they all seem to assmume I want to bake the light in, which I assume I dont want to, with an object thats going to be animated as its lighting will change?

So my questions are:
1) Is this the right thing to do at all?
2) If so what bakes do I do, and with what settings?

Here is the node tree, and [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7j7fkaa8svn0tv1/cube.blend?dl=0) The material is called glowing grebble and is applied to the ship hull.

Thanks so much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirected Bounces in closed rooms are heavy in general. But simplifying your Material could help a bit.

When your goal is to simplify the shader and to do the hole material with one Principled Shader you have to pool all the shader channels and bake masks separately (emission, roughness, color, etc.)
Add-On Node Wrangler and its "Viewer Node" does help a lot (Ctrl + Shift Click to Get a Emission Output of the clicked node) You want to always bake via emission channel to not get shadows in your bake. (Maby im wrong on that part and it would be easier to just bake the passes via the bake menue instead of pooling them in the shader editor, have to test it tomorrow)

1. as an example I put all the emissions as absolute white to get a mask that produces 100% emission at the needed areas.
2. Create a Image Texture Node in your material. Doesn’t have to be connected, but has to be selected! Because of your procedural textures you have to use a huge resolution to get the details. The example pic has only 1k texture for reasons of baking speed..
3. Cycles Render Panel > Bake > emmission pass: uncheck selected to active, set margin low or 0, hit bake with image texture node in node editor selected.
4. Image Editor > Save Image! Otherwise you will loose the data.

For your other channels (color, roughness etc.) just pool them together and route them to the viewer node.
After Baking all the Maps plug then In your principled shader and you should save the calculation time for the 4d procedural noise textures.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I'm rendering a test run now. I'll try this when it's done later today :D